# Where is Element.clientWidth with fractional number?

Tags: javascript, html

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) that `Element.clientWidth` "will round the value to an integer" and I should use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` instead for a fractional value. While the part with the fractional value is correct, that function has a different meaning and cannot be compared.

`clientWidth` gives me the inner visible width without the vertical scrollbar. `getBoundingClientRect` gives me the outer width including the vertical scrollbar. These are entirely different sizes.

Is this intentional? Does the MDN article know about that difference? Should that restriction be added to the cross-link? What else can I do to get the desired value, which is the visible width with a fractional value?

My problem is that I'm writing code that hides elements that won't fit in the current view, depending on the view width and the elements' width. Therefore I sum up all elements' widths and compare it with the space I have. At certain window sizes, that can lead to the element width sum of 945.4 (that fits in) and the `clientWidth` giving me 945 (same value but rounded down, so it's less). `getBoundingClientRect` however gives me 951.2 in this case which is more than is actually available for the content. In consequence, a horizontal scrollbar appears which I don't want.

Comment: I stumble upon this problem too, sadly the only related info that I could found was a Chromium Bug from 2017 closed with WontFix: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=360889
I'll continue searching for alternatives.. the biggest issue is the scroll bar width, I guess that the workaround will be to pre-calculate the scroll bar width and take that from the bounding client rect

Comment: any luck so far, @Diego? I have also stumbled into this now. I am not managing to find a way of calculating the scrollHeight precisely =)